# UIPinchGesture Not working on MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, xib

I added pinch recognizer to the view(in which I have added MPMoviePlayerController) and created a function to handle pinch (i have set IBAction for that function) but it did not enter that function. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController has its own implemented gestures recognizers that work on MPSwipableView. These gestures are already modified to perform specific default operations that MPMoviePlayer uses.

- To define a custom gesture over MPMoviePlayerController. you have to use a separate empty view, add it over your MPMoviePlayerController.
- Add Gesture Recognizers on it. Now you can receive gestures on your empty view. According to that you can adjust your MPMoviePlayer's View frame.

Answer (score 0):

add delegate to pinch recognizer,MPMoviePlayerController and enable user interaction for MPMoviePlayerController,

```
pinchreg.delegate=self;
player.delegate=self;
player.userinteractionenabled=yes;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `umirza47` answer is to deactivate the `pinchgesture` recogniser attached to the `MPMoviePlayerController` view. It depends though if you need to have the zoom in/zoom out functionality on the movie player for your own purpose: i believe that what the pinchgesture recognizer is for on the movie player:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in ((UIView *)videoVC.moviePlayer.view.subviews[0]).gestureRecognizers) {

     if ([gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {

                gesture.enabled = NO;
     }
}
```